# Change Row name of a particular Column in Dataframe

Tags: r

How to change Row name of a particular column in R dataframe:

```
<df

Name    Value
A       10
B       20
C       30
```

I want output to be:

```
Name    Value
AAA     10
BBB     20
CCC     30
```

I have tried data.table library but it couldn't work.

```
library(data.table)
my_df <- setattr(df$Name, "row.names", c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC"))
```

Comment: Tried this but it's not changing the Values under "Name" head, it created new row name.

~           Name    Value
  AAA    A          10
  BBB    B          20
  CCC   C          30~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the name column is it's own column.  See the code below

```
sample <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), Value = c(10,20,30))
```

Looks like this:

```
  > sample
 Name Value
1    A    10
2    B    20
3    C    30
```

Now Try:

```
sample$Name <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
```

Yields:

```
> sample
  Name Value
1  AAA    10
2  BBB    20
3  CCC    30
```